# In Ubuntu 20.04 how do I add custom page size for printer

Tags: 20.04, printing

How do I add custom page size to a printer. I do not see an option to set my own page size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Such printer wizard menus may look different in different application. Which application do you use on screenshot? In which application do you want to get custom page size?

Comment: @N0rbert I have updated the question. This is for HP Deskjet 2700 in that printer options

Comment: have you installed CUPS? please [edit] your question accordingly. [Installing CUPS](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-cups)

Comment: Is there no "custom" option at the top of the list you show in your second picture?

Comment: @vanadium no that was what I looked for at first and did not see any option

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Kubuntu. Any solution yet?